# Put a dot above a bold symbol in an equation?

Tags: equations, bold

I know this is a really basic question, but I'm a newbie with Latex.  How can I put a dot (to indicate the time derivative) above a bold symbol in an equation?  When trying `$\dot \mathbf{x}$`, I get an error, and when trying `$\mathbf{\dot x}$`, I don't get an error but the symbol doesn't display correctly.  I assume there's some simple way to do this.

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is `$\dot{\mathbf{x}}$`. The syntax is `\dot{<symbol>}`. You are missing the braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $\dot{\mathbf{x}} \dot{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you only get this error if you use the `amsmath` package - and that is why it is always a good idea to give a *complete* "minimum working example" of your problem, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\dot \mathbf x$ % doesn't work
\end{document}
```

Even with `amsmath`, `$\dot x$` works correctly without braces. But the usual cause of weird error messages like `\select@group has an extra }`, which is what I got from 
`$\dot \mathbf x$` with `amsmath`, is that something (in this case `\dot`) is effectively being applied just to the next *token* in the input, and `$\dot \mathbf$` doesn't make any sense on its own.

Note also that `$\dot{\mathbf x}$` and `$\mathbf{\dot x}$` are not the same. The second one gives a bold-face dot over the bold-face x, unlike the first one.